# android geocoder getFromLocationName returns results even when found address is not inside bound box

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding

android geocoder getFromLocationName returns results even when found address is not inside bound box. How could I solve this or the only way is to check it manually?

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488890/android-getfromlocationname-return-results-outside-the-bounding-box), but it has no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a mistake getFromLocationName works correct when used with bounds. It only returns results out of bounds if you will enter city name.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same method for the same purpose,I didn't found the Perfect solution for this but my ways how i used is posted ,See the answer I have posted in that **[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488890/android-getfromlocationname-return-results-outside-the-bounding-box)**