# How to make an autocomplete address search text box that retrieves the same result as Android Maps?

Tags: android, dictionary, autocomplete, textbox

I've created an autocomplete address search text box. My problem is that I just can't make it work fine:

1. Addresses are out of the bounding box usually, whatever I do - [this didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488890/android-getfromlocationname-return-results-outside-the-bounding-box).
2. Finds addresses that doesn't contain the typed text.
3. Finds less addresses, than max but it doesn't contain the good result.
4. The result list is totally irrelevant sometimes.
5. I need to type almost the whole address to get the correct result.

Source:

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
       List<Address> addresses = null;
          try {
             if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                // Bounding box: Hungary
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(text, 5, 46.13, 21.96, 48.89, 16.69);
             }
          } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.v(tag, "Geocoding error: " + e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

My aim is to make an address search text box which gets the same result as in Android Maps seach text box - except the previously typed/favourite addresses and etc., which is an other story.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) may be of help. As far as I know you must license it for use in commercial apps. If your app is for free then you should be fine.

**EDIT** about inaccurate Geocoder results:

I haven't yet played around much with Geocoder. But what I can tell you so far is the following:

You need to take into consideration that on some devices all methods return null (check Geocoder.isPresent() to be sure) because Geocoder relies on some underlying implementation that can be missing on some devices.

And it is also possible that these results come from an other Geocoder engine / service than Google Places.

On top of that the query results are never perfect. You rarely get the exact address of the current location either because the location is off or because the Geocoder data is not accurate enough (or simply outdated).

If you really need an accurate address you should give the user both a list of best candidate options and some means for manually editing the address.

If you need more accurate results based on the location name you could take a look at available online services that perform better for your needs. One example is geonames.org. If their database is good enough for you, then you need to get or implement some Java API for interfacing with the service of your choice and use that instead Geocoder.

Comment: Thanks! By the way I can't see why geocoder.getFromLocationName() doesn't give the correct result. Isn't there any way to make it work fine?

Comment: I updated the source in my question (Geocoder.isPresent()) - just like I'm using that in my code; it wouldn't return anything if those implementations didn't exist. And I'm not expecting exact results; I want to get the same result for the typed address fragments like in Google Maps in my (HTC Desire HD) device. Since it works perfectly in that, I think I could expect to make this work in my application too. Or what method/implementation uses GMaps?

Comment: @KárolySzabó I checked your bounding box geo coordinates (lower left and upper right). Considering that "up" is North and "left" is west you are confusing up with down. Instead of specifying lower left and upper right coordinates you pass over "upper left" and "lower right" coordinates. You need to move up your first coordinate and move down the second. If that still doesn't work try explicitly setting the locale to English and check the results.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the parameters were wrong (it was my 10th version), I corrected: addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(text, MAX_RESULT, 45.619673, 16.957397, 48.812169, 23.098755) - but it still does the same. Locale.getDefault() returns: Locale HU - which is perfect - I'm in Hungary! I tried to set it ENGLISH, and it works different. But setting back to default (HU) is still works bad. (For example: trying to find Debrecen, and typing: 'de' -> result: 'Delaware' - definetely not a Hungarian city. And so on...) Any idea?